# how to change the format of graphique in ggplot to combine geom_col and geom_surface

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics, geom-col

I'm trying to plot with ggplot my data frame by using the code bellow

```
p1 <- ggplot(dates2, aes(x=periode_ap, y=pourcentage_parc, fill=apport))+
        geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE))+
        ylim(0,100)+
        scale_fill_manual(values=mycolors, name="")+
        theme_light()
```

i get this graphic
[image: picture]
but what i want is this one ::

[image: picture 2]

how can i change my code to get the right graphic please !!! or i must use another package not ggplot to do that !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you post your data, we can work with that.  Otherwise, here's an example of something that should work.  Use a combination of `geom_area` and `geom_line` with your data, and adjust `fill=` and `color=` aesthetics, respectively for each.

```
df <- data.frame(
  x=c(4,5,6,7,8:15,10,11,12,12,13,14,15),
  y=c(0,100,0,0,20,20,40,10,10,10,10,0,0,50,0,0,60,60,0),
  id=c(rep('Big Peak',3), rep('Other Thing',9),rep('Another Item',3),rep('At the end',4))
)

ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + theme_bw() + xlim(0,20) +
  geom_area(aes(fill=id), alpha=0.2, position='identity') +
  geom_line(aes(color=id), size=0.8) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=expansion(c(0,0.22))) +
  theme(legend.position=c(0.8,0.8), legend.background = element_rect(color='black'))
```

[image]

A potentially important aesthetic is to adjust the `scale_y_continuous` expansion to 0 for the bottom limit in order to avoid whitespace there.  Otherwise, your area geoms will be "floating" over the x axis line.

Comment: :Thanks a lot Normaly it must Work